# What is compex?

Tags: java

I found a bunch of java files online and there is one function that appears all over the place but i cannot find the definition of on google: `compex`. google keeps on sending me to complex, no matter how i use symbols to make `compex` an important search term. it doesnt seem to be imported from anywhere. all i have managed to find out about it is that it takes 2 single integers as inputs.

i am not a java programmer. im just trying to figure out what in the world the code means

```
/*
 * PermSortAlgorithm.java
 * Patrick Morin takes no responsibility for anything. So there.
 *
 */

/**
 * A PermSort Demonstration algorithm.  The PermSort algorithm is due
 * to Patrick Morin <http:www.scs.carleton.ca/~morin>.  The algorithm
 * works by trying every permutation until it finds one that's
 * sorted.  That's right, there are n! permutations and it takes O(n)
 * time to test each one, yielding an O(nn!) algorithm.  No hate mail
 * please.
 *   
 * @author Patrick Morin 
 */
class PermSortAlgorithm extends SortAlgorithm {


    /**
     * Check if the input is sorted.  Do it in a weird way so it looks
     * good for the sort demo.
     */
    boolean issorted(int a[], int i) throws Exception {
    for (int j = a.length-1; j > 0; j--) {
        compex(j, j-1);
        pause();
        if(a[j] < a[j-1]) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }

    /**
     * Privately sort the array using the PermSort algorithm.
     */
    boolean sort(int a[], int i) throws Exception {
    int j;

    // Check if array is already sorted
    if (issorted(a, i)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Array wasn't sorted so start trying permutations until we
    // get the right one.
    for(j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
        compex(i, j);
        pause();
        int T = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = T;
        if(sort(a, i+1)) {
        return true;
        }
        T = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = T;
    }
    return false;
    }

    /** 
     * Sort the input using the  PermSort algorithm.
     */
    void sort(int a[]) throws Exception {
    sort(a, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a code snippet, where it is imported and used.

Comment: no. i specifically said that i do not mean `complex`

Comment: No you didn't, calcrypto. If you want more help, you'll have to give us more context.

Comment: whoops. i mistyped `complex` as `comples`

Comment: Easiest way to help us: show a link to one of those *millions* of java source files (or Java API docs) ;) Then we could look at the code inside or read the javaDoc

Comment: Actually your question says "google keeps sending me to comples".  If google automatically redirects you to what it thinks you meant, there will be a link underneath the search field that you click to search for what you literally typed instead.

Comment: I added a link to the end of the original post.

Comment: Hey actually I don't get the downvotes or votes to close. Could someone explain?

Comment: @calccrypto - looked at the referenced page and half of the sources and couldn't find a single `compex` operation. More specific please.

Comment: @calccrypto - be more specific.  I searched the linked page and a few of the algorithms it linked to and couldn't find any mention of "compex".

Comment: @PabloFernandez - it is because he is feeding us incomplete information and causing us to waste our time trying to figure out what he is talking about.  In short, it is a bad question.

Comment: sorry. i looked at the websites again, and they dont have it, so im going to post a code i found somewhere or another

Comment: @StephenC some people simply have problems writing their thoughts, specially if they are not native english speakers. The question was __correctly__ answered in less than 6 minutes by Ignacio so it wasn't __that__ hard, was it?

Comment: @PabloFernandez - A good (inspired) answer doesn't make the question good.  The problem is not that the question was hard ... it is that it was asked in such a careless way.  (And the problem is nothing to do with the OP's language skills.  It is careless things like providing a link to a bunch of pages that don't contain the example at all.)

Comment: And why again do morons downvote a very interesting question? And why got it even closed? Well it is answered now ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's short for [compare-and-exchange](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/498/notes/node33.html).

Comment: thanks. how hard was that? thanks for the `-1`s

Comment: @calccrypto - it is easy to figure out once you provide us the CORRECT information.  The -1's are for not doing that in the first place ... or the second place ... and wasting lots of peoples' time.

Comment: Looking at the code provided it seems unlikely that the function does compare-and-exchange because in the first call of the function the first parameter is always larger than the second (and the second one isn't even an lvalue) and in the second call the latter parameter is always larger.

Comment: @calccrypto It does not seem to be quite compare-and-exchange. I found PermSortAlgorithm at http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~morin/misc/sortalg/PermSortAlgorithm.java. In the same directory sortalg there is also SortAlgorithm.java and SortPanel.java, the first of this attributed to @author James Gosling, @version  1.6f, 31 Jan 1995 and Modified by Pat Morin on Feb. 7 1996. `compex` is defined in `SortAlgorithm`, which forwards it to `SortPanel.compex` where it is documented to **Change the position of the comparison exchange marker.**